# Plotting temperature cycles (heating, cooling, heating) on the same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a set of data where there's a temperature cycle that first cools down, then heats up, and cools down again (so it goes from 25C to -90C, then from -90C to 230C and then it cycles again). I want to get the graph where the x axis (temperature) rather than cycling back, continues to expand. So rather than it going from 230 to -90 the x axis does something like: 20 to -90, -90 to 230, 230 to -90... and so on (like on this example:[image]

Is there any way this can be done? (the temperature and y axis data are collected form an xls and uploaded using the pandas library) I have the time data with which I can plot the graph and make it look like the one bellow, but I don't manage to add a secondary x axis where the temperature is shown as explained before, which is what I need.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: you got temperature and time on the x-axis? whats the y-axis?

Comment: the Y axis is data about the heatflow to a material. It's also uploaded from the same excel file to a dataframe